# Trying to put a start button in a javascript game snake game

Tags: javascript, button

I have tried to put a start button to my game or a start menu , but every time I try something my game stops working , I have tried a lot of stuffs that I have found online but every time it do-sent work and my game just disappear.

My game is a Snake game in javascript ,that I am trying to insert in my web page, I have found the script online I am not very good in coding. I have just started.
I know some things and I am learning every day but I still consider my self a noob.

So this is the script 
i wana put the start button in front of the game

my script begin by //   body onload="init()"
the body onload , i dont have see it in the examples that i had see online

```
function init() {

    var ctx;
    var turn = [];
    var xV = [-1, 0, 1, 0];
    var yV = [0, -1, 0, 1];
    var queue = [];
    var elements = 1;
    var map = [];
    var X = 5 + (Math.random() * (45 - 10)) | 0;
    var Y = 5 + (Math.random() * (30 - 10)) | 0;
    var direction = Math.random() * 3 | 0;
    var interval = 0;
    var score = 0;
    var inc_score = 50;
    var sum = 0, easy = 0;
    var i, dir;
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');





    for (i = 0; i < 45; i++) {
        map[i] = [];
    }




    canvas.setAttribute('width', 45 * 10);
    canvas.setAttribute('height', 30 * 10);
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    function placeFood() {
        var x, y;
        do {
            x = Math.random() * 45 | 0;
            y = Math.random() * 30 | 0;
        } while (map[x][y]);
        map[x][y] = 1;
        ctx.strokeRect(x * 10 + 1, y * 10 + 1, 10 - 2, 10 - 2);
    }
    placeFood();
    function clock() {
        if (easy) {
            X = (X + 45) % 45;
            Y = (Y + 30) % 30;
        }
        --inc_score;
        if (turn.length) {
            dir = turn.pop();
            if ((dir % 2) !== (direction % 2)) {
                direction = dir;
            }
        }
        if (
            (easy || (0 <= X && 0 <= Y && X < 45 && Y < 30))
            && 2 !== map[X][Y]) {
            if (1 === map[X][Y]) {
                score += Math.max(5, inc_score);
                inc_score = 50;
                placeFood();
                elements++;
            }
            ctx.fillRect(X * 10, Y * 10, 10 - 1, 10 - 1);
            map[X][Y] = 2;
            queue.unshift([X, Y]);
            X += xV[direction];
            Y += yV[direction];
            if (elements < queue.length) {
                dir = queue.pop()
                map[dir[0]][dir[1]] = 0;
                ctx.clearRect(dir[0] * 10, dir[1] * 10, 10, 10);
            }
        } else if (!turn.length) {
            if (confirm("nice try,keep winning satoshis ! Play again? Your Score is " + score)) {
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 450, 300);
                queue = [];
                elements = 1;
                map = [];
                X = 5 + (Math.random() * (45 - 10)) | 0;
                Y = 5 + (Math.random() * (30 - 10)) | 0;
                direction = Math.random() * 3 | 0;
                score = 0;
                inc_score = 50;
                for (i = 0; i < 45; i++) {
                    map[i] = [];
                }
                placeFood();
            } else {
                window.clearInterval(interval);
                window.location = "/projects/";
            }
        }
    }
    interval = window.setInterval(clock, 60);
    document.onkeydown = function (e) {
        var code = e.keyCode - 37;
        /*
            * 0: left
            * 1: up
            * 2: right
            * 3: down
            **/
        if (0 <= code && code < 4 && code !== turn[0]) {
            turn.unshift(code);
        } else if (-5 == code) {
            if (interval) {
                window.clearInterval(interval);
                interval = null;
            } else {
                interval = window.setInterval(clock, 60);
            }
        } else { // O.o
            dir = sum + code;
            if (dir == 44 || dir == 94 || dir == 126 || dir == 171) {
                sum += code
            } else if (dir === 218) easy = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this good?

```html
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
     <style>
        canvas {
            border: 1px solid;
        }
        #btn {
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Start" onclick="init()" id="btn" />
    <script>
        function init()
        {

            var ctx;
            var turn = [];
            var xV = [-1, 0, 1, 0];
            var yV = [0, -1, 0, 1];
            var queue = [];
            var elements = 1;
            var map = [];
            var X = 5 + (Math.random() * (45 - 10)) | 0;
            var Y = 5 + (Math.random() * (30 - 10)) | 0;
            var direction = Math.random() * 3 | 0;
            var interval = 0;
            var score = 0;
            var inc_score = 50;
            var sum = 0, easy = 0;
            var i, dir;
            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            for (i = 0; i < 45; i++)
            {
                map[i] = [];
            }
            canvas.setAttribute('width', 45 * 10);
            canvas.setAttribute('height', 30 * 10);
            ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);
            function placeFood()
            {
                var x, y;
                do
                {
                    x = Math.random() * 45 | 0;
                    y = Math.random() * 30 | 0;
                } while (map[x][y]);
                map[x][y] = 1;
                ctx.strokeRect(x * 10 + 1, y * 10 + 1, 10 - 2, 10 - 2);
            }
            placeFood();
            function clock()
            {
                if (easy)
                {
                    X = (X + 45) % 45;
                    Y = (Y + 30) % 30;
                }
                --inc_score;
                if (turn.length)
                {
                    dir = turn.pop();
                    if ((dir % 2) !== (direction % 2))
                    {
                        direction = dir;
                    }
                }
                if (
                    (easy || (0 <= X && 0 <= Y && X < 45 && Y < 30))
                    && 2 !== map[X][Y])
                {
                    if (1 === map[X][Y])
                    {
                        score += Math.max(5, inc_score);
                        inc_score = 50;
                        placeFood();
                        elements++;
                    }
                    ctx.fillRect(X * 10, Y * 10, 10 - 1, 10 - 1);
                    map[X][Y] = 2;
                    queue.unshift([X, Y]);
                    X += xV[direction];
                    Y += yV[direction];
                    if (elements < queue.length)
                    {
                        dir = queue.pop()
                        map[dir[0]][dir[1]] = 0;
                        ctx.clearRect(dir[0] * 10, dir[1] * 10, 10, 10);
                    }
                } else if (!turn.length)
                {
                    if (confirm("nice try,keep winning satoshis ! Play again? Your Score is " + score))
                    {
                        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 450, 300);
                        queue = [];
                        elements = 1;
                        map = [];
                        X = 5 + (Math.random() * (45 - 10)) | 0;
                        Y = 5 + (Math.random() * (30 - 10)) | 0;
                        direction = Math.random() * 3 | 0;
                        score = 0;
                        inc_score = 50;
                        for (i = 0; i < 45; i++)
                        {
                            map[i] = [];
                        }
                        placeFood();
                    } else
                    {
                        window.clearInterval(interval);
                        window.location = "/projects/";
                    }
                }
            }
            interval = window.setInterval(clock, 60);
            document.onkeydown = function (e)
            {
                var code = e.keyCode - 37;
               
                if (0 <= code && code < 4 && code !== turn[0])
                {
                    turn.unshift(code);
                } else if (-5 == code)
                {
                    if (interval)
                    {
                        window.clearInterval(interval);
                        interval = null;
                    } else
                    {
                        interval = window.setInterval(clock, 60);
                    }
                } else
                { // O.o
                    dir = sum + code;
                    if (dir == 44 || dir == 94 || dir == 126 || dir == 171)
                    {
                        sum += code
                    } else if (dir === 218) easy = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: You welcome. But if my answer helped you it is better to check it or upvote. Maybe some body could use this post.